# Two stacked elements after a }

Tags: stack

I'd like to express a set of vectors by {a_n} followed by a little column with two elements, the size of the set and n=1, as they usually are in some books. How can I create that column? I've tried with \stackrel{N}{n=1}, but it looks very big. Is there any other way?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I tried, but strangely I couldn't find any elpful image that could ilustrate my question. Anyway, I got my answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like the following?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \{a_n\}_{n=1}^{N}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: That's so simple I didn't even think it would work. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 4):

Or maybe this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a_n \big\vert^{N}_{n=1}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer your solution than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Without a MWE, perhaps what you want is something like this?:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\left. \right|^{N}_{n=1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or using the `a_n` vector:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$a_n\left.\right|^{N}_{n=1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `a_n\bigr|_{n=1}^{N}`? That way you leave no *unwanted* space.

Comment: @Manuel ahhhh, I didn't know that :).  thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Manuel what is the difference between \bigr| and \vert?

Comment: @MarioS.E. - The symbols produced by `\vert` and `|` are identical. The former, though, is more "LaTeX-y" since it focuses more on the symbol's meaning than its concrete shape.

Comment: @MarioS.E. Well, I used `|` but you can use `a_n\bigr\vert_{n=1}^{N}` if you prefer.

Comment: What is the \right. for?

Comment: @carllacan it for declaring the `|`.  You can use it also with `\right)`, `\right}`, etc.